# Starting a new Activity within doInBackGround() of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

In my project, I need to trigger an inquiry about the user's action every 1h. This should be done in AyncTask(In fact, I am modifying an existing code).
Can I start a new activity in doInBackGround() of AsyncTask? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can start the activity directly from the doInBackground() method as it is running on a different thread than the UI thread. I think an activity has to be started on the UI thread. But you could probably start it on the onProgressUpdate() which is execute on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

In onPostExecute you could start a new activity, haven't try to start an activity in doInBackground but it seems possible.